# Elasticsearch - Sharding and Performance

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, elasticsearch-5

I think I've finally gotten a grasp of the fundamental understanding of how to allocate shards for Elasticsearch. Please correct me if I'm wrong, this is what I've pieced together:

1. Ideally, there should only exist one shard per index, per node.
2. The only reason **why** we would ever want to configure more than
   one shard **IS** to over-allocate for future growth (i.e. adding more
   nodes to physically support the data).

Now, assuming what I have above is correct, I then wonder if there are **any** performance issues or differences if I only had **one node with 1 shard versus one node with 5 shards**. Can anyone enlighten me on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

"The only reason why we would ever want to configure more than one shard IS to over-allocate for future growth (i.e. adding more nodes to physically support the data)."

Not necessarily so. Having more shards helps parallelise your queries and helps them finish faster, but after a bit it can be counterproductive as too many shards will mean overheads in merging the individual shard responses and time spent in queuing and such things.

"one node with 1 shard versus one node with 5 shards"

It depends on what your use case is but you should see some performance gain for bigger queries, with 5 shards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on the size of the shards. For instance, on the elastic website, they say the following:

> "Querying lots of small shards will make the processing per shard
>   faster, but as many more tasks need to be queued up and processed in
>   sequence, it is not necessarily going to be faster than querying a
>   smaller number of larger shards. Having lots of small shards can also
>   reduce the query throughput if there are multiple concurrent queries."
>
> https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

In practice I have found that using some exploratory testing with realistic queries helps me determine more definitively how I should move forward with my architecture. It really depends on the use case. As was stated previously however, there comes a point where you can sort of "over optimize" and it ends up cancelling out any noticible gains you may have otherwise obtained by doing the opposite solution.

To be succinct, one shard per index, per node is a fine practice. But if you find yourself needing more, then just assess your use case first and determine if additional shards are truly necessary.